# Is this an overfitted network?

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, keras, training-data

I have obtained this result after training a neural network in keras and I was wondering if this is overfitting or not.

I'm having doubts because I have read overfitting is produced when a net is overtrained, and it happens when the validation loss INCREASES.

But in this case it doesn't increase. It remains the same, but the training loss DECREASES.

EXTRA INFO

Single dataset split on this way:

- 70% of the dataset used as training data
- 30% of the dataset used as validation data

**500 EPOCHS TRAINING**
[image: Loss results]

**2000 EPOCHS TRAINING**

[image: 2000 epochs]
[image: 2000_zoom]

Training loss: 3.1711e-05
Validation loss: 0.0036

Comment: It looks good to  me.

Answer (score 3):

There is a slight overfit in the sense that you training loss keeps decreasing and the validation loss stopped decreasing.

However, I wouldn't consider this harmful because the validation loss insn't increasing. This is if I read the graph correctly, if there is a small increase then it's getting bad.

A harmful overfit is when your validation loss starts increasing. The validation loss is your true measure of the performance of the network. If it goes up then your model is starting to do bad things and you should stop there.

All in all this seems pretty decent. The training loss will almost always be going lower than the validation at some point, this is an optimization process over the training set.

Comment: I'm glad to hear about this (I mean, the fact that is not a harmful overfitting because the validation loss doesn't increase). But...at which point can we say this model is valid? Now that I have training with 2000 epochs, the different is enormous in a little scale (0.0036 vs 3.1711e-05 validation loss). Where can I set the limit in order to know until which level of overfitting I can admit a valid model?

Comment: It's up to you, pick the model which has the lowest validation loss... it should give you the best perf since it's performing good on "unseen data" :)

Comment: It's ok, I think I understand

Answer (score 2):

Training loss does indeed appear to continue decreasing further than validation loss (it still looks to me like it didn't finish decreasing yet at the 500th epoch, would be good to continue for more epochs and see what happens). The difference doesn't appear to be large though.

It may be overfitting slightly, but it may also be possible that the distribution of your validation data is simply a bit different from the distribution of the training data.

I'd recommend testing the following:

1. Continue for more than 500 epochs, to see if the training loss keeps on decreasing even further, or if it stabilizes close to the validation loss. If it keeps on decreasing much further, and the validation loss stays the same, it's safe to say that the network is overfitting.
2. Try creating different splits of training and validation sets. How did you determine training and validation sets actually? Were you given two separate sets, one for training and one for validation? Or were you given a single large training set, and did you split it up yourself? In the first case, the distributions may be different, so a difference in training vs validation loss wouldn't be strange. In the second case, try randomly creating different splits and repeating the experiments to see if you always consistently get the same difference in training vs validation loss, or if they're sometimes also closer together.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. 
I have a single large dataset and then i divide it myself by making the following split: training 70% of the dataset / validation 30% of the dataset.

Now I am training again with more epochs, and I'm going to edit the post in order you can see the result.

And I will also try some different split ans say what happens.

Comment: @Jvr saw the plot for 2000 epochs. That looks stable, so that doesn't look like an amount of overfitting to be worried about, if any.

Comment: Really glad to read this! :) thanks a lot. I will also wait for other opinions, anyway.